# onBackPressed() of my activity does not get called when my activity pops up a dialog

Tags: android

I have implementation `onBackPressed()`, it works when there is no popup alert dialog from my activity. But when my activity pops up a dialog, `onBackPressed()` never get called.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
// more implementation.
}
```

How can I detect back key is pressed by user when a dialog is pop up?

Thank you.

Comment: instead try giving a back button on the alert-dialog, it wil b easier to implement and detect

Comment: easier to implement and detect what?

Comment: implement a "ok" or "BACK" button on alert dialog, y exactly u want to detect a back press?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, should do the job.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        yourpopup.dismiss();  // or whatever you want todo here
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: android provides onBackPressed() for the same

Answer (score 2):

Well, in that case [Dialog#onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onBackPressed%28%29) will be called, which is expected behavior.

Comment: I need to subclass AlertDialog to implement this?

Comment: AlertDialogs are Dialogs, so yes if you want a specific behavior you should subclass AlertDialog. The default implementation calls cancel() if cancellable on BACK.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your Activity doesn't have focus at that point. You'll have to add a button listener to the dialog that pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create your own custom Pop-up message class which extends AlertDialog.Builder, and handle the user selection on the pop-up window (i.e. Yes/No, Submit/Cancel buttons) using a Java Interface.

That's the way I did it, so I could handle warnings and errors, other alerts using my own custom alert pop-up message window.

I didn't have to do anything special in the custom Pop-up message class to handle the back-button being pressed.

However, I did handle the back-button being pressed in the activity class that calls my custom pop-up message class.

```
/**
   * onKeyDown method
   * 
   * Executes code depending on what keyCode is pressed.
   * 
   * @param int keyCode
   * @param KeyEvent
   *          event KeyEvent object
   * 
   * @return true if the code completes execution, false otherwise
   * 
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
      //handle the back-key press here

    default:
      return false;
    }
  }// end onKeyDown
```